# Alfresco 5 support for multi-tenancy

Tags: alfresco

I just downloaded and installed Alfresco in order to take a look at the new features in version 5 (http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2014/07/01/3899).

I also wanted to take a look at Alfresco's support for multi-tenancy, however, I can't navigate to (403) the "Tenant Admin Console" (after first logging in as admin to Explorer) as per http://gagravarr.livejournal.com/146003.html (and the the Alfresco wiki).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this on Alfresco 5.0a Community Edition installed using the binary installer on Mac OS X 10.9.4 and JDK 1.7.0_51.

Double-check your tenant console URL and try again:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/faces/jsp/admin/tenantadmin-console.jsp
```

Comment: Hi Jeff,

I used the binary installer to install Alfresco 5.0a CE on OSX 10.9.3 and JDK 1.7.0_60.

I get a 403 for all the JSPs in the /admin folder.

I have checked the file permissions + had a look at the web.xml file in /WEB-INF:

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Admin Authentication Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/faces/jsp/admin/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>

Could the Admin filter be returning a 403?

Cheers
Rob

Comment: OK, I reinstalled Alfresco, used the Advanced installation type and ONLY selected PostgreSQL (Java and Alfresco).

I was then able to start Alfresco, login in to Explorer as "admin" and navigate to the Tenant Admin console :)

I had previously also selected LibreOffice, Google Docs Integration and Web Quick Start.

Comment: Ahh, I may also have checked "SharePoint" which would install the CIFS server which isn't supported for multi-tenant configurations.

So, perhaps Alfresco then restricts access to the multi-tenant admin console?

Comment: Checking "SharePoint" installs the VTI server, which supports the SharePoint File Sharing Protocol and is unrelated to CIFS. In any case, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they removed it from CE v.5.0.b onwards. If you want multi-tenancy, try downloading 5.0.a

Okay, okay... here's an "Answer" -- Download 5.0.a -- It has multi-tenancy. The reason you're getting 403 is because it's no-longer in 5.0.b onwards.

Once you have 5.0.a installed, login as an admin. Then navigate to http://localhost:8080/alfresco/faces/jsp/admin/tenantadmin-console.jsp

If you want a later version, then you'll have to use the 30-day trial of Alfresco One (non-community edition)

Comment: It is not an answer. Put it as comment.